# Io exception: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, hibernate, sockets

I'm getting a **Software caused connection abort: socket write error** in my Code when connected to a particular Oracle DB only . with other DB it works fine. Below is the error

```
WARN - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: null
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
failed org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException                at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionCaused by:   
 **java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Software caused connection abort: socket write error**
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:648)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.privateClose(OraclePreparedStatement.java:485)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.close(OraclePreparedStatement.java:393)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:563)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:291)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:307)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:234)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1967)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
```

i have below method Which uses hibernate Criteria

```
public List<SET> findMaxProcessId(Session session, Site logS) {
        try {
        List<SET> listRackIdProcessed = new ArrayList<SET>();
        List<Integer> listMax= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<CInvoicingProcessResult> IistMax= findRackIdWithMaxInv(session, logS);
            // session.getTransaction().setTimeout(120);
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(InvoicingProcess.class);
            manageListInvProcessId(crit, listMax); 
                   //Here it check if List is greater than 1000 if yes it divides it in subList
            crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("set")));
            listProcessed = crit.list();  // **Getting ERROR HERE**
            // session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        return listProcessed;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

I have also tried using session.getTransaction().setTimeout(120); too but didn't work.

```
Why is this error Occuring when i try to get > crit.list()
```

I'm not able to find any solution.

Comment: Don't know the reason. but the error is solved by removing manageListInvProcessId(crit, listMax); from the findMaxInvProcessId method above

Comment: The duplicate tells you why. It's a network problem.